# ODRefreshControl in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableView that gets data from Parse. I want it to reload the data when the user pulls down and releases (like the feature in the mail app) When I added ODRefeshControl, the animation worked fine, but nothing was shown on the app itself. I'm new to iOS development, if you could go a bit in-depth would be great!

Comment: Do you expect the refresh control to do magic? How have you set it up? Have you added listeners to state changes so your app hears it needs to load data? If you don't post all information, we can't help you.

Comment: Also, why are you using `ODRefeshControl` instead of the native `UIRefeshControl`?

Comment: Well I added both ODRefreshClasses. I clearly stated I got the animation working but it is not showing in the UITableView, like a part of it is hidden. I don't know how to use the UIRefreshControl.

Comment: `ODRefeshControl` is an old open source implementation of `UIRefreshControl`, meant for iOS5. You should be using `UIRefreshControl`. You use it in the same manner as `ODRefreshControl`.

Comment: Alright, I'll look it up, thanks for the help!